# DPS Payment Gateway (Px Fusion) integration in Magento

Tags: web-services, magento, soap, payment-gateway, credit-card

I have a created website using magento in which i want to use the online payment produce DPS Payment Express (Px Fusion) Gateway..

However, I don't Know how to go and create about Px Fusion (http://www.paymentexpress.com/Technical_Resources/Ecommerce_NonHosted/PxFusion)
I only can find free standard extension using PxPay & PxPost (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dps-paymentexpress-by-magebase.html)

This is my first time using for magento. I don't know how should i do? pls advice for me (or) share sample code for me. Thanks.

Comment: Please contact us on devsupport@paymentexpress.com. We will send you a plugin for for PxFusion and Magneto.

Comment: Hi Shobhonk, Contact for what? Last time, we contact they only give the above link. they never give to plugin. PxFusion plugin send from you or devsupport ?

Comment: I work for DPS. We have recently created a new plugin for Magento and PxFusion. I don't have your email from here otherwise I would have sent you the plugin already.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the official PxFusion extension for Magento here: http://www.moustacherepublic.com/extensions/payment-express-dps-pxfusion.html